# Как написать (не) слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

"Совершенно (не)нужное решение" - где есть (не), как его написать: слитно или раздельно и почему? Скажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно ненужное решение. Прилагательное с НЕ пишу слитно. т.к. приставка НЕ придает противоположное значение, возможна замена на синоним - лишнее. 
А вот вторую часть вопроса не поняла. Вам про все случаи написания НЕ рассказать? ТАм много нюансов. Но если кратко, то: с глаголами, деепричастиями и краткими причастиями всегда раздельно (не путать с приставкой НЕДО); с прилагательными, существительными, наречиями на -О(Е)слитно, если можно заменить синонимом; с полными причастиями при отсутствии противопоставления и зависимых слов - слитно. Если не употребляется без НЕ - естественно, слитно любая часть речи. С числительными все отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Очень сомнительно само смысловое наполнение данного предложения. В какой ситуации мы можем так сказать? Видимо, автор предполагает, что решений может быть несколько? Например, одно не очень нужное решение, второе почти нужное и третье - совершенно ненужное?

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно ненужное решение. Здесь  "ненужное"    прилагательное.  Общее правило таково: прилагательные с НЕ пишутся слитно, если НЕТ противопоставления с союзом А, слов ВОВСЕ, ОТНЮДЬ, ДАЛЕКО, и слов с приставкой НИ- (нисколько, ничуть и т.д.)Поэтому пишем слитно.